# Permutations with matching

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, matching-theory, derangements

Suppose that I have the set $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. I will label the elements as $S_i$ where $i=1,…,5$. So, for example, $S_1=1, S_2=2$ and so on. I call $\tilde{S}^k$ Any permutation of $S$ for $k=1,…,5!$.

I want to find the number of permutations $\tilde{S}^k$ of $S$ such that

1. $\tilde{S}_i \neq S_i$ for any $i$ (So, the first element must be different than 1, the second element different than 2 etc..)
2. $\tilde{S}_i \neq S_j$ for any $i\neq j$, where $j$ can be either one index or a subset of the indexes $1,2,3,4,5$(For example, if $j=1$, the first element of these permutations must be 1, if $j\in \{1,2\}$ the first and second element must be 1 and 2 respectively and so on).

Is there a general approach to tackle these kind of questions?

**EDIT**

As someone complained about the lack of context of my question, let me make a concrete example where this problem may arise.

Let's say that we have two identical decks of 5 cards each. Each card is numbered from $1$ to $5$. We shuffle both decks and we put the first deck' cards on a row, face down. We then put the cards from the second deck, face-up, one over each of the other cards. I want to compute the following probabilities

1. $p_0 = p(\text{No cards match})$
2. $p_1 = p(\text{Only 1 matching})$
3. $p_2 = p(\text{Only 2 matchings})$
4. $p_3 = p(\text{Only 3 matchings})$
5. $p_4 = p(\text{Only 4 matchings}) = p_5=  p(\text{Only 5 matchings}) $

There are 5! possible permutations. Therefore, to compute $p_0$ I need to count how many rearrangements of 5 cards there are, such that  the first card is not 1 AND the second card is not 2 AND the third card is not 3 and so on.

By direct counting, I know that there are 44 such permutations (see image below), therefore $p_0 = 44/5! = 11/30$.
[image]

Let's take now $p_3$.
This case is simple, since the problem asks for exactly 3 matchings and, give three matchings, the other two numbers either match or not. Therefore, for each combination of 5 over 3 elements, there is only one possible permutation, and
$$
p_3 = \binom{5}{3}\frac{1}{5!} = 1/12
$$

I can keep going on, but I think the question should be clear now.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun These are related questions.  Users should be discouraged from asking *unrelated* questions.

Comment: @Shaun there is no further information or context in the question because there is none. All the information you need is in the question. I think it’s pretty clear what I am asking about. The two questions are related to each other. Your comment is no sense

Comment: No, @apt45; you're supposed to share your thoughts on the problem. What are you studying? What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise? What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with? What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else? Is this question something you think should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: @Shaun I have just asked myself this question. There is no context. I am a theoretical physicist but I am not too familiar with combinatorics and permutations in such special cases. I think that my thoughts would just complicate the question (just because I know they are wrong because they don’t provide the right counting). Why should I confuse the readers by posting calculations that I know are wrong?

Comment: How can  you be a member here for over seven and a half years and yet not know the etiquette surrounding context?

Comment: @Shaun yes, ask yourself why. Maybe if there would have been a context I would have written it. I’ll come up with an example where this question may arise. Give me 10mins

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Groups of derangements: what is known about subgroups of a symmetric group $S_{n}$ that contain only derangements (plus the identity)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3126593/groups-of-derangements-what-is-known-about-subgroups-of-a-symmetric-group-s-n)

Comment: @Buraian: That's not true. For instance, $(123)(4)$ has an odd number of elements that are mapped to themselves.

Comment: @Buraian: Above you wrote "odd order sets", now you write "odd order group" – which one do you mean. I did accidentally write an example for a set with an even number of elements, but $(1234)(5)$ works just as well for a set of five elements. All permutation groups except $S_1$ are of even order, so if you do mean the group order, I'm not sure which groups you're referring to.

Comment: @Buraian Question improved with context and a probability example.

Comment: @Shaun Question improved with context and a probability example

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this problem is easy if expressed in terms of counting derangements. The solution is simply then

$$
p_k = \binom{n}{k}\frac{!(n-k)}{n!}
$$

where $!x$ is the sub-factorial.